# Where is the ArcGIS ServicePackFinder 9.3 utility found?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, installation

Where is the ArcGIS ServicePackFinder 9.3 utility found?  I know it's for download, but no amount of trawling can find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://downloads2.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/PatchFinder93.exe